# GitHub Code Space for Extension Development

Tags: extensions, github, opensource

We are developing Magento 2 extension and publish them as open source on GitHub. It would be cool if contributors can launch up a GitHub code space and make edits + tests the changes.

Is there already a prebuilt code space configuration for this?

I think we need to script the Magento installation? Maybe with Magerun?

Did anybody do this already?

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer of this question? I am looking for this

Comment: no, I did not get find an answer